# I got an error that says curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 18332: Connection refused

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I could succeed to work the testnet at once.However after I restarted my Mac,bitcoind came not to work.

Answer (score 1):

bitcoind doesn't restart after your computer restarts. Start bitcoind after you start your computer.